# vue data share another component

Tags: vue.js

[image]After uploading an image, I want to pass the returned result to another component. Is there a way?
Dropzone =>Return the result.

```
dropzoneOptions: {
                url: 'http://localhost:5000/',
                method: "post",
                maxFiles: 1,
                thumbnailWidth: 300,
                maxFilesize: 500,
                success: function(file,responejson){
                      this.msg = responejson
                    console.log(this.msg)
                  },
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                dictDefaultMessage: "<i class='fa fa-cloud-upload'></i>Drag & Drop"
            },
```

I want to move the json value in msg to another component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there can be two cases here:

1. Passing data from parent to child component ( using props )
   `https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props`
2. Passing data from child to parent component ( listening to child events )
   `https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events`